# Shared database in Lotus Notes with user accounts

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino

I have a easy and generic question to Lotus Notes. I want to achieve the following configuration:

Multiple users uses one database located on the Notes server. Every user has a Notes client and works on the own replica. But what I need is that only I have permissions to read and edit documents of everyone. The users should have access only to own documents and not documents from other users. I don't want that documents of all users are replicated to the local database of everyone.

How to achieve this? Do you know a good tutorial to this basic configuration? Thank you!

Comment: By the way, there is no "Notes server" anymore. About 20 years ago, Lotus renamed the server software to "Domino".

Comment: Also, is there a need for the users to work on local replicas? Why not work directly on the server?

Answer (score 1):

Add a field of type "Readers" and a field of type "Authors" (both computed when composed) to all forms in this database and set value to:

```
@Author : "[Admin]"
```

Set access to "Author" for all users with option "Create documents" in database's ACL.

Add a role "[Admin]" in ACL and assign it to yourself.

Set option "Enforce a consistent Access Control List across all replicas" in ACL to make sure that users have the same right on client like on server.

Comment: For a more in-depth tutorial on what Knut is talking about, see here; http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/lotus/library/reader-names/

Comment: Thank you! I will check it out.